SQL error: unknown geometry type: 13 - PolyhedralSurface
Basically I'm making a database for an assignment that creates tables constraints etc.
I have 3 tables which are top middle and bottom level. I need to insert data into these tables, of which includes geometry data.
I have written this SQL for the top level table:
insert into ucesfur.mines(mine_name, total_capacity, location)
values ('Mine A', 10000, 
        st_extrude(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((400000 200000 0, 400010 200000 0, 400010 200010 0, 400000 200010 0, 400000 200000 0))', 27700), 0, 0, 200)),
       ('Mine B', 8000, 
        st_extrude(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((400020 200020 0, 400030 200020 0, 400030 200030 0, 400020 200030 0, 400020 200020 0))', 27700), 0, 0, 200));

This works perfectly fine.
Next I need to input data into a table called mining_sites. The mines table has a mine_id serial PK, which mining_sites takes as a FK.
The issue I come across here is that I need to use the FK from the geometry instead of the mine name.
So the query cannot look like this:
INSERT INTO mining_sites (site_name, mine_id, production_rate, geometry)
VALUES ('Site A1', 1, 150.00, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((400001 200001, 400004 200001, 400004 200004, 400001 200004, 400001 200001))', 27700)),
       ('Site A2', 1, 200.00, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((400006 200006, 400009 200006, 400009 200009, 400006 200009, 400006 200006))', 27700)),
       ('Site B1', 2, 180.00, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((400021 200021, 400025 200021, 400025 200025, 400021 200025, 400021 200021))', 27700));

Where the mine_id is hard coded as 1 or 2. I need it to query the mine id from the intersection of geometry.
Now, I've written the query as so:
insert into ucesfur.mining_sites (site_name, mine_id, production_rate, location)
values ('Site A1',
        (select mine_id 
         from ucesfur.mines 
         where st_intersects(location, 
st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((400002 200002, 400008 200002, 400008 200008, 400002 200008, 400002 200002))',27700))),
500.00,
st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((400002 200002, 400008 200002, 400008 200008, 400002 200008, 400002 200002))',27700)
);

However, I get an error

ERROR: Unknown geometry type: 13 - PolyhedralSurface

The insert into mining_sites statement is causing this error, but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried replacing the geometry data with the one from the mines table insert but still get the error.
I have very particular instructions which are I have to use the ST_INTERSECT query to get the mine_id FK and can't use a workaround. I have a feeling its something to do with the ST_INTERSECT statement maybe not being able to take 3D data but I may be wrong.
Any idea of a fix for this issue?
Thanks.

You can use ST_3DIntersects():
insert into ucesfur.mining_sites (
       site_name
     , mine_id
     , production_rate
     , location )
select v.site_name
     , m.mine_id
     , v.production_rate
     , v.geom
from ucesfur.mines as m
join(values('Site A1'
           ,500.00
           ,st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((400002 200002
                                     ,400008 200002
                                     ,400008 200008
                                     ,400002 200008
                                     ,400002 200002
                                    ))',27700)
           )
    )as v(site_name,production_rate,geom)
on st_3dintersects(m.location,v.geom);


Note that in your example, incoming row with more than one matching mine location breaks the query while in mine, you'll get duplicates if an incoming geometry turns out to intersect more than one mine at a time. Also, my example discards incoming rows that don't have a matching mine, while yours inserts them with a null - that can be fixed by using a right join or switching them around and making it a left join.
